# Cannot include WooCommerce-CustomerClass to other PHP-File

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I am using WooCommerce 3.5.2 on Wordpress 4.9.8.
At the moment I am trying to build a custom template for "WooCommerce PDF Invoices & Packing Slips" and want to show a text-field only if the customer is not located in the homebase of the woocommerce-shop.
I found a function called "is_customer_outside_base()" in "woocommerce/includes/class-wc-customer.php" and calling this function in my Template-File. At the beginn of the File I use the following code to load  the class-File

```
$path = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'];
$path .= '/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/includes/class-wc-customer.php';
require_once($path);
```

But I receive an error message everytime I generate an invoice:

> Fatal error: Call to undefined function is_customer_outside_base()

I have no idea, why this is not working, the path seems correct, I put an echo "$path" in the file and the output was: /var/www/vhosts/easy/httpdocs/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/includes/class-wc-customer.php

The template-file has the following path:
/var/www/vhosts/easy//httpdocs/wp-content/themes/corporate-pro/woocommerce/pdf/simple_ww_new/invoice.php

I hope for your advice. Thank you!

Comment: if you require `wp-load` you should get access to all of wordpress functions - which should also include woocommerce functions.

Comment: like `require_once('../../../../wp-load.php');` - not sure how many steps you need to go out

Comment: `require_once(rtrim($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'], '/') . '/wp-load.php');`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The require is working fine, otherwise you'd be faced with a fatal error for that, before it could reach the undefined function fatal error.

Are you referencing the class in the function call?

i.e. are you doing this: `WC_Customer::is_customer_outside_base()`

instead of just this: `is_customer_outside_base()` (won't work)

?

Comment: That was the problem! I always thought there is maybe a security issue, but as always the problem is in front of the screen. Thank you!